# Add own metrics to Prometheus that returns list of integer instead of just a number

Tags: java, spring, prometheus, metrics

I have an application in Java Spring that uses Prometheus metrics.
Is it possible to add a new meter, that will not return a number,
but a whole list of integers?
Below is a sample of the response, that I would like to have.

```
# HELP INVALID_IDS
INVALID_IDS{CAUSE="Timeout"} 978, 019, 100...
INVALID_IDS{CAUSE="Resource not exists"} 420, 510...
INVALID_IDS{CAUSE="Resource expired"} 291, 309...
```

After each call for metrics, all lists would be cleared, and new IDs would be returned:

```
# HELP INVALID_IDS
INVALID_IDS{CAUSE="Timeout"} 4310,...
INVALID_IDS{CAUSE="Resource not exist"} 4512
INVALID_IDS{CAUSE="Resources expired"} 4620, 4900,...
```

I already found that there are possible to collect only four types:

- Counter
- Gauge
- Histogram
- Summary

But none of these fits my needs. So my question is: is it possible to achieve this somehow?

Comment: Maybe [Export String based Metrics](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65881775/6771046)?

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible.

Whenever you have such an idea, you should stop and reconsider if you are using metrics correctly.

Based on example you provided I suggest you not even trying to use metrics for this. Metrics will be appropriate for exposure of total errors per cause (as a counter).

But for individual cases of incorrect data you should use logging solutions. If you are already familiar with Prometheus, you might consider [Grafana Loki](https://grafana.com/oss/loki/), as it has similar query syntax. Additionally, if you already have those invalid ids stored in your logs, you might even avoid modification of application, and pushing logs using Promtail.